# Interacting with web based game

Tags: python, facebook, http

I would like to create a script, that will play for me a facebook game and I would like to write it in Python. Could you point me to some tutorial about how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Reddit thread on "Making a game bot using Python"](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/et759/making_a_game_bot_in_python/) has some good replies relevant to this.

Comment: This is nice, but wouldn't be better to send my own POST requests? This way I can run it easily in the background.

Comment: POST request? I don't think that the games on facebook apps send each and every user keystroke to the server i.e. you would be mistaken to think that each and every user move maps to a HTTP request. AFAICT, only final scores are sent to the server.

Comment: It is as web based game, like crims or red dragon. I don't know, if you played any of them. Anyway, it's basically a static web site, where you operate by following links or sending requests (clicking buttons, that send them). That's way clicking is not as good. In fact, one round is just a few clicks and then you have to wait until you refresh pool to act again. That's why I would like to be able to send some requests with my actions and then simply sleep my program for 5 minutes and let it run again and again. But clicking is cool, I can just push one, very cool action all the time.